# How do I add headers in Tomcat web.xml?

Tags: tomcat

We are adding security headers for our websites and we are trying with options available. we have fixed the security headers in Apache servers under httpd.conf file.

Now we are updating the security headers for our websites which are running on tomcat, we tried with options available on goolge after surfing nothing worked.

We need to update following headers for our sites, can anyone help us on this.

```
Strict-Transport-Security 
Content-Security-Policy 
X-Frame-Options 
X-XSS-Protection 
X-Content-Type-Options
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
      <param-value>2592000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>      
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>     
    <init-param>
      <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
      <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>
      <param-name>blockContentTypeSniffingEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>
      <param-name>xssProtectionEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> 
  </filter>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>/*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresDefault</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 1 days</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  
  <error-page>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to enable the `Content-Security-Policy` header ?

Comment: were you able to get the csp working via tomcat? or did you have to hard cod the value in the HTML?