# Content security policy header in tomcat9

Tags: security, tomcat, content-security-policy, policy, tomcat9

i want to add content security policy header in tomcat.I am able to add x-frame header by changing webxml file.but i do not if i can add content security policy header in the same way.
please help on this

Answer (score 1):

Using the `web.xml` file you can [publish some security headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898029/how-do-i-add-headers-in-tomcat-web-xml), for example `X-Frame-Options`, `X-XSS-Protection`, but not the `Content-Security-Policy` one.
Because `web.xml` config is based on built-in Tomcat filters which does not support CSP header yet. Therefore, you need to create [custom servlet-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306300/can-tomcat-7-be-configured-to-insert-content-security-policy-http-header), which can then be used in the `web.xml` file.

You can found some nitty-gritty about custom filter creation in the [grails-x-frame-options-plugin](https://github.com/mrhaki/grails-x-frame-options-plugin/blob/df230a9f01cd2e1c6ac4be6d9eac41fbcae48293/src/main/groovy/com/mrhaki/grails/plugin/xframeoptions/web/XFrameOptionsFilter.groovy), based on XFO header.
[OWASP](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Content_Security_Policy) also has a detailed example of a CSP filter.